# Simple association with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model, form-helpers

I recently started looking into CakePHP - which I'm so far loving. However, I need to ask a fairly simply question:

It's about model association. I got 2 models User and Group. A User can have multiple Groups and a Group can only have one User. So I've made it like this:

```
<?php
class Group extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Group';
    var $belongsTo = 'User'; 
}
?>

<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = 'Group'; 
}
?>
```

And then on the add-group page I want it to be possible to select the user from a dropdown. My Group add view is as follows:

```
<h1>Add Group</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Group');
echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('pincode');
echo $this->Form->input('private');
echo $this->Form->end('Create group');
?>
```

The user_id automatically transforms to a dropdown - however without any options. What do I need to do? I assume I need to put somewhere that it should get the "name" from the User table.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer in the documentation (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements).

And the solution is:
Group controller in the add method:

```
$this->set('users', $this->Group->User->find('list'));
```

And in the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
```

Nice and simple. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should set a variable in the Group controller's add-group function:
`$users = $this->Group->User->find('all', array('fields' => array('DISTINCT User.user_id')));`
`$this->set('user_ids', $users);`

Then in the view, create the input like this:
`echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('options' => $user_ids));`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. We're getting there - however this answer prints all columns in the dropdown. Meaning there will be an option for date, name, id, etc from the user table. I just want the "name" from the User tabel.

Comment: Yes, right, I updated the code. But it's definitely more neat with 'list'.